# Do Not Disturb for specific duration in Samsung S8 Quick Settings

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-8, do-not-disturb

I've just switched from a Sony Xperia Z3 (6.0) to the Samsung Galaxy S8. On the Sony I could set Do Not Disturb mode for a specific time (15 mins, 30 mins, an hour, 2 hours and so on) using the Quick Settings menu.

This was a really useful feature when going into meetings, presentations, movies etc. But I can't find this feature on the S8 - there's only the option to enable DND mode (and leave it on) or schedule it between specific times.

Is there anyway to get the great 'DND for 15/30/60 etc. minutes' feature in the Quick Settings on the S8?

Comment: This applies to Samsung S10 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see in Google's documentation for the Pixel that the feature that lets you set how long DND mode should last (15,30,60.. minutes) is there in the Pixel, just as it was in my old Sony Xperia:
https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6111295?hl=en

Unfortunately it looks like Samsung removed this feature with their Touchwiz overlay, so you're only left with scheduling DND between specific times or enabling it forever.

To bring back this feature I ended up having to install an app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cabooze.buzzoff&hl=en

Answer (score -1):

Galaxy S8 has the feature. Its there in sound settings.

**From home, swipe up to access Apps.**

**Tap settings app icon Settings > sounds settings icon Sounds and vibration > Do not disturb.**

**Tap On/Off to enable the feature.**

You can also schedule the mode.

**Tap Turn on as scheduled, and set the Days, Start time, and End time.**

Source: http://eguides.sprint.com/support/eguides/samsunggalaxys8s8plus/content/samsung_galaxy_s8_s8_plus_ug/do_not_disturb.html

Comment: Also you can enable it in quick access by editing quick access list.

Comment: I asked how to enable DND for a specific time period like 15/30/60 etc. minutes, this doesn't answer that. I already know how to enable DND mode (and leave it on) or schedule it between specific times